# Apt wildcards with exclusion

Tags: apt, 20.04

I am trying to install all `fonts` packages except `fonts-mathematica`.  What is the best way to go about this?

I started with the command below:

```
apt-get -y install *fonts*
```

Regards,
j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apt` new patterns. Use `man apt-patterns` for more info.

List all packages which their names contains "fonts" and count them:

```bsh
$ apt list '~n.*fonts.*' 2> /dev/null | wc -l

573
```

Filter out the output using `grep` to look for `fonts-mathematica`:

```bsh
$ apt list '~n.*fonts.*' 2> /dev/null | grep -i mathematica

fonts-mathematica/focal 21 all
mathematica-fonts/focal 21 all
```

To exclude it:

```bsh
$ apt list '~n.*fonts.* !?exact-name(fonts-mathematica)' 2> /dev/null | 
grep mathematica

mathematica-fonts/focal 21 all
```

Or even to exclude both of them:

```bsh
$ apt list \
'~n.*fonts.* !?exact-name(fonts-mathematica) !?exact-name(mathematica-fonts)' |
 grep mathematica
```

So here is what you are looking for:

```bsh
$ sudo apt install \
'~n.*fonts.* !?exact-name(fonts-mathematica) !?exact-name(mathematica-fonts)'
```

And it would definitely end up with a lots of conflicts.

What we can do is to generate a list of all these packages:

```bsh
$ apt list \
'~n.*fonts.* !?exact-name(fonts-mathematica) !?exact-name(mathematica-fonts)' | 
cut -f1 -d/ > 2>/dev/null fonts_lists
```

Or even in a cleaner way:

```bsh
$ apt-cache search --names-only fonts | grep -v -e fonts-mathematica -e mathematica-fonts | cut -f1 -d' ' > fonts_list
```

Then use a guide like this: "[Continue on error when apt-get encounters an install unable to locate package issue](https://superuser.com/questions/837662/continue-on-error-when-apt-get-encounters-an-install-unable-to-locate-package-is)" to install them one by one.